# Recursion in Matlab. why is my recursion not working past the first step?

Tags: matlab, recursion, matrix

So I am very new to Matlab and I have been tasked with implementing LU factorization.  I have to do it recursively because we are not allowed to use for loops in our code, and recursion will give us optimal marks.  I have written this code.  The code works for the first step, and does what it is supposed to, but for the next two steps, the matrix is not modified at all. I have this code:

```
function[L, U] = myLU(A,B, pos)
%A = Mtrix that becomes U
%B = Matrix that becomes L
    tmp_L = B;
    [x,y] = size(A);
    if pos > x
        L = B; 
        U = A;
        return
    else
       pos %<-- just to see if it iterates through everything
       [tmp_U,tmp_L] = elimMat(A,pos);
       myLU(tmp_U,tmp_L, pos+1);
    end
    L = tmp_L; 
    U = tmp_U;
end
```

I where `elimMat(A, pos)` returns the elimination matrix for column pos. as well as another matrix, which will end up being the matrix of multipliers.  What i tried doing is then finding the LU factorization of this matrix `A`.  since elimMat returns L and U(this works, if i do it manually it works), i had to make a function that allows me to do it automatically without using a for loop.  I thought i would do it recursively.  What i ended up doing is adding another variable `B` to the function so that i can store intermediate values of my matrix obtained in each step and put it all together later.

So here is my question.  Am i implementing the recursion wrong?  and if i am how can i fix it?  The other thing i wanted to ask is how can i implement this so i do not need variable `B` as an additional imput, and only use the existing variables, or variables previously defined, to find the solution?  I would really like only two inputs in my function:  The matrix name and the starting index.

here is `elimMat` if if helps:

```
function [M,L] = elimMat(A,k)
    %find the size of the matrix
    [x,y] = size(A);
    tmp_mat = zeros(x,y);
    %M = The current matrix we are working on for Elimination -> going to
    %become U.
    %L = The L part of the matrix we are working on.  Contains all the
    %multipliers. This is going to be our L matrix.
    for i = 1:x
        mult = A(i,k)/A(k,k);
        if i > k            
            tmp_mat(i,k) = mult;
            P = A(k,:)*mult;
            A(i,:) = A(i,:)-P;
        elseif i == k
            tmp_mat(k,k) = 1;
        end
    end
    M = A;
    L = tmp_mat;
end
```

thanks for any feedback you can provide.

Here is the output: WHAT I GET VS what it should be:

```
[U =                    VS           [U = 

 1     2     2                        1   2   2
 0    -4    -6                        0  -4  -6
 0    -2    -4]                       0   0   2

L =                         VS       [L= 

 1     0     0                        1   0   0
 4     0     0                        4   1   0 
 4     0     0]                       4  0.5  1
```

As you can see only the first column is changed

Comment: Regarding your first code block: you don't need to write backticks if you use indent-based code formatting. Although proper matlab syntax highlighting is missing from SO, your first block is even worse this way:) And the comments at the start of `elimMat` might be confusing: a function's first contiguous piece of comment lines after the function header are its help. If you type `help elimMat`, you should see the first comments of the code. To avoid this, leave an empty line after the function header (at least I think that should fix it. Either that, or put an empty comment after the header).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. i will look into making those changes as soon as i get my code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to catch the output of your recursive call:

```
[tmp_L, tmp_U] = myLU(tmp_U,tmp_L, pos+1);
```

Matlab passes variables by value, so a function cannot change its input variable itself (ok, it can, but it's tricky and unsafe).

Your original version didn't return the updated matrices, so the outermost function call encountered the `myLU()` call, let the recursion unfold and finish, and then went on to use `tmp_L` and `tmp_U` as returned from the very first call to `elimMAT(A,1)`.

Note that you might want to standardize your functions such that they return `U` and `L` in the same order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I cant believe I overlooked the result assignment.  This worked for the first part. and U comes out correctly.  I still have the issue with L however.   Do you have any idea how to fix the other problem I have?  I would like to remove the tmp_L from the funciton call and still have it give me back L?

Comment: wait nvm. i am just not passing it in the function. that would explain why it is not working.

Comment: @MD-4 I don't exactly understand what the problem is, but your second commend tells me that there might not be a problem at all. Let me know if there's something still:)

Comment: haha sorry.  I was having problems with one of my matrices not adding correctly. i solved the problem. I simply forgot to add the,

Comment: thank you for the answer. i have been away from the computer for a while.

Comment: @MD-4, no problem at all, I'm glad I could help:)